# How to easily determine in SwiftUI / Xcode which types can be passed when method parameter is Protocol?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, xcode11

I am new to SwiftUI and not very old with Xcode either. I am not sure if it is only my doubt or is it the way SwiftUI/Xcode supposed to work.

For example if I look at `Text("").border` or `Text("").background` then as per Xcode autocomplete one is supposed to pass a type confirming to ShapeStyle or View. Since Color extends both View and ShapeStyle so one can supply Color to border and background like `Text("").border(Color.black)` or `Text("").background(Color.gray)`

[image]

[image]

I may be asking for too much but neither the apple developer documentation nor Xcode made it clear or easy for a developer to determine that Color could be passed.

I can see if a developer already knew or researched that Color implements View and ShapeStyle then such a person can write the code in first instance but for a newbie it is not easy to deduce that Color could also be supplied when documentation and Xcode's autocomplete suggest to supply View and ShapeStyle.

Question is, is this the way it is supposed to work like a developer has to have a good knowledge on types and hierarchy or is there any way one can (especially newbie) easily see which concrete types can be substituted by following apple developer documentation and/or something in Xcode which I might not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing fancy in that regard as of Xcode 11.5.

What classes conform to protocols like View / ShapeStyle can be looked up in the documentation of the protocol under "Relationships/Conforming types":

[image: Relationships/Conforming types]

It helps to read a lot of practical SwiftUI code to absorb such ideas.
The example project from the [SwiftUI tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/tutorials) is a good start.

Comment: Thanks Ralf for the inputs. After your reply I took a notice of "Relationships/Conforming types" section in developer documentation but it appear it is not exhaustive. If I look at documentation for ShapeStyle then it doesn't list Color as something that conforms to ShapeStyle and View but Color does both. I have Xcode 11.3.1/Mojave 10.14.6